# Heroku clone project without git

Tags: facebook, heroku

i'am using heroku in order to devellop a facebook app. I have some troubles with clon my project with git (it only work at home, not at work) ([Heroku error for getting the code from git](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/15896385/heroku-error-for-getting-the-code-from-git?noredirect=1#comment22640721_15896385))

how i can download the code store on heroku without git ?

(i find how to push code without git [Deploying changes to an app hosted on Heroku without using Git](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5806929/deploying-changes-to-an-app-hosted-on-heroku-without-using-git/15949181?noredirect=1#comment22727283_15949181))

thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your SSH keys use [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) on your work machine and it should work ;)

Comment: the key generation or even though you generate the second key, it wont work? What is the error, when you try to clone the repo? Try moving your work to cloud ide, that would be a solution.